# How to divide/convert/assign the data which send back from json_encode()

Tags: jquery, json

In php file, array $lines includes two array(i.e. $line1 and $line2). After that, array $lines encoded by json_encode() as a string then send back to success: function(data).

Here I want to 
1.divide $lines into $line1 and $line2 
2.convert $line1 and $line2 into array format
3.assign $line1 and $line2 to a js variable seperatly.

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

```
$.ajax({
           type:"post",
           dataType:"json",
           data:{"minVal":2, "maxVal":200, "sid":<?php echo $id ?>},
           url:"getData.php",
           cache: false,
           success: function(data) {

                     var arr = data;

                     }
           });

    <?php
    $line1= array(array("08:00","18"),array("09:00","22"),array("10:00","21").array("11:00","26"));
    $line2= array(array("08:00","54"),array("09:00","47"),array("10:00","52"),array("11:00","58"));

    $lines = array($line1,$line2);

    ?>
```

Comment: what does data look like now?

Answer (score 0):

not very clear but when you want line1 and line2 in a var you do

```
var line1 = data[0];
var line2 = data[1];
```